# Driving a JSP Page with Dropdown

Tags: nodes

We are using Drupal to drive the fields on a JSP page on a Java web site.  I can easily enough create a Long Text field and populate it with text such that a text element becomes a radio button or input field on the JSP.

But I also need to drive input fields that have dropdown items.

I am casting about looking for ideas of how to do that without brute-force programming.

Comment: What do you mean by "drive the fields"?

Comment: I bring the fields over from Drupal and splash them across a JSP with a for loop.